# Mesh deforming while moving bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm trying to do a simple character to try mesh rigging but when I move the bones, my mesh is deforming/changing scale.

The weight paint seems good so I don't understand the problem.

[image]

Here is a video that shows the issues:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIRY9.jpg

Comment: The weight painting is definitely not good from what I am seeing, parts of the arm mesh may still be weighted to other bones that are contributing to the weird skewing and distortion.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the images only. Can you share the file? Otherwise, check the face orientation, the weights, the vertex groups, and that there is only 1 armature modifier on the mesh. Also, the mesh and the armature must have the same rest pose when you bind them (Parent To ...). And the *Scale, Rotation*, and *Location* of the armature should be applied before the bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my main body bone weight was applied to all the body...